How to prevent a Composable from allowing clicks or scroll events to pass through
Basically, I have two Box composables:
A red box that occupies the full screen.
A green box with a higher zIndex, which makes it appear on top of the red one:

The issue:
When I click somewhere over the green box, the click is also detected in the red box, along with scroll and every other interaction.
My question:
How can I make the green box stop interactions from passing through to the red box underneath?
the code:
class TEST : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            KdoumaScoreTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {cc->
                    cc // just to evoid the error of not using the inner padding

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(Color.Red)
                            .clickable {
                                Toast
                                    .makeText(this, "shouldn't happen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                    ){

                    }
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                            .fillMaxWidth(0.6f)
                            .background(Color.Green)
                            .zIndex(100f)
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Please note that making the underlying composable not clickable or not scrollable is not the goal; I want to make the above one non-pass-through.

Can you try changing the order of the red and green box in the scaffold to check if it works?

First of all this is not a question about gesture going through. For that to happen there has to be parent-child relationship so gestures propagate from child to parent with default pass. If that was the case consuming gesture on child would prevent parent receiving it or changing propagation direction from parent to child and consuming in parent would do the trick based on your desired outcom.
From ui perspective it might look going through but from propagation perspective but what you want  is sibling Composable to not receive any gestures.
For that to happen check down and up on green Composable so red one does not receive events.
@Preview
@Composable
fun SiblingGesturePreventionTest() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Scaffold { padding ->
            padding

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.6f)
                    .background(Color.Green)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        awaitEachGesture {
                            awaitFirstDown()
                            waitForUpOrCancellation()
                        }
                    }
                    .zIndex(100f)
            )

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier

                    .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .clickable {
                        Toast
                            .makeText(context, "Red is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
            ) {
                Column {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp).background(Color.Magenta))
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp).background(Color.Cyan))
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp).background(Color.Green))

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

